# next and previous buttons to retain the states

Tags: javascript, html, session, cookies

I am integrating a quiz section into my website. I will be displaying one question with its options at a time, the questions would be retrieved from the database. I will be adding the Next and Previous buttons below the questions for the navigation to the respective questions incase the user want to review before submission.

During the button clicks with the Next and Previous buttons **how do I retain the radio button states(checked and unchecked) ?**

Comment: Anything you have tried yet?

Comment: No. Just the frontend